# How to validate if message is sent from MS teams to Microsoft bot

Tags: botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

Before processing message by bot I want to validate if the message is send from MS teams and someone is not impersonating.

Something similar to this https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack

Comment: I have given the solution and you can validate the same.

Comment: What are risk you are thinking when you are saying impersonating?
Basically, if user wants to send something to your bot, will need the details like conversation Id and others which user external to Teams can't get it.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT Also need to verify that something is not changed on wire.

Answer (score 0):

Each "turnContext.Activity" will contain the Channel information, So before processing, you can identify the channel in the bot framework.

```
turnContext.Activity.ChannelId
```

You can process the activity in the following way. Here "Channels" will be part of the "Microsoft Bot Connector" package.

```
if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == Channels.Msteams)
   {
     //do your activity
   }
```

Microsoft Bot Connector has the following channel information.

[image]

**Reference:**

- [Channel Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Comment: But any one who calls the API can impersonate the request but setting channel to teams, right?

Comment: Any one can pass but ms teams is part of AD tenant so you can add security layer to prevent those unwanted distractions also no need to expose this kind of api to unauthorized users. every channel have different kind of format in botframework.

Comment: @Mahesh Yes, you can do this way. Have you tried this solution?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT I couldn't figure out how to do it . It would be helpful if you can point to any example.

Comment: @Mahesh did you tried the above scenario in your application ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach for you is to use *[Authentication flow for bots in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-bot)*
Please see point 8.b :

> Validate what's received from Teams. A two-step authentication
> validation is performed to ensure that the user who authorized the bot
> with the identity provider is the same user who is chatting with the
> bot. This guards against man-in-the-middle and phishing attacks. The
> bot generates a verification code and stores it, associated with the
> user. The verification code is sent automatically by Teams as
> described below. ([View code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node/blob/469952a26d618dbf884a3be53c7d921cc580b1e2/src/AuthBot.ts#L100-L113))

Thanks.